# Failed to stop alert fire twice using flag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Try to write a validation library but stuck on somewhere. How to alert only once although they are 2 validation layer?

```
var validation_event = {
    mandatory: function(that) {
      if (!$(that).val() && $(that).data('placeholder')) {
        alert('Please fill in ' + $(that).data('placeholder') + '.');
        return false;
      }
    },

    email: function(that) {

      var regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
      if ($(that).val() == '' || !regex.test($(that).val())) {
        alert('Please make sure the ' + $(that).data('placeholder') + ' is valid.');
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/

Try to click submit, you will see there are 2 alert. Other than that things are working fine.

Comment: If you want to quit from the $.each you can use `return false`  see https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/3/

Comment: if you want to show all messages you need to collect them first and then trigger one alert at the end

Comment: @XzenTorXz it should alert email is not valid, ur example doesn't work

Comment: thats why i posted a comment, because i'm not sure what you're trying to achive @Eunice-Chia

Comment: @XzenTorXz if the user didn't enter the email , it will alert the user the email address filed cannot be empty, if the user entered something, but the email is not valid, the user shall see alert of 'please make sure the email is valid.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/5/

Comment: please read my answer and mark it as solved or add an comment to clearify your question

Answer (score 0):

@XzenTorXz 's fiddle is correct answer i.e. https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/3/

your mistake is that your validation is returning the false after alert, but you never use that value to stop the `$.each`. You need to stop `$.each` after first alert.

Comment: it doesn't trigger the alert of saying the email is not valid. Check the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var options = ['mandatory', 'email'];

  var validation_event = {
    mandatory: function(that) {
      if (!$(that).val() && $(that).data('placeholder')) {
        alert('Please fill in ' + $(that).data('placeholder') + '.');
        that.stopPropagation();
      }
    },

    email: function(that) {

      var regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
      if ($(that).val() == '' || !regex.test($(that).val())) {
        alert('Please make sure the ' + $(that).data('placeholder') + ' is valid.');
        that.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: he passes the jquery element, not an event so stopPropagation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a single message:

You can use the `return false` to break out of the `$.each`. You also need to return true on a successfull validation: https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/4/

If you want to have multiple message shown (if multiple validations fail) you need to collect your messages (returning them from validation) and alert them at the finish. See https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/6/. You could also combine the 2 so that you only have 1 message per field, see: https://jsfiddle.net/wvzbq9h2/7/